# 2d Unity character tipping over blocks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I'm a new Unity Coder and a bit stumped with a problem. When I jump onto a object using Rigid body 2D, There seems to be a centre of gravity kind of thing going on where my character tips over the platform. It there a fix for this where when the whole bottom of it drops when the whole thing is off?

Player Tipping Over

[image: Player Tipping Over]

RigidBody Settings
[image: RigidBody Settings]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have any constraints. Constraints basically tell the Rigidbody2D which way it can rotate and which way it can move. If you click the little `Constraints` drop-down menu in the Rigidbody2D settings, you should get a menu that has

> FreezePosition  [] x   [] y

> FreezeRotation  [] z

Since we are in the 2D, the only axis we can rotate along is the z (z is the blue axis that goes through the player). You should click the check box next to z to constrain it along that axis.

> FreezeRotation [#] z

This way, the Rigidbody2D is not allowed to rotate based on its physics.